# HTTP Response headers not set when using IIS Integrated Pipeline Mode

Tags: c#, http-headers, iis-7.5, httpresponse, webclient

I have an web-application developed using C# and EXT.NET in Visual Studio 2015, and have implemented a method that downloads a file using the HTTP response. The user clicks a download button on a row in a grid, and the file is downloaded. This works perfectly fine when I am running the application locally on my computer. Once i publish and installs the application on my **IIS webserver (v8.0)** located on a **Windows 2012 Server**, it doesn't work any more. Every time the download button is clicked a popup is displayed with the following message:

***Request Failure***

**Status Code:**

**Status Text: *BADRESPONSE: Unexpected token <**

In the codebehind method i use the response to write the file

```
// Clear the content of the response
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();

// LINE1: Add the file name and attachment, which will force the open/cance/save dialog to show, to the header
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.Name);

// Add the file size into the response header
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());

// Set the ContentType
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

//Response.Redirect(url, true);

// Write the file into the response (TransmitFile is for ASP.NET 2.0. In ASP.NET 1.1 you have to use WriteFile instead)
Response.TransmitFile(fileInfo.FullName);

HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); // Sends all currently buffered output to the client.
HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  // Gets or sets a value indicating whether to send HTTP content to the client.
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); // Causes ASP.NET to bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline chain of execution and directly execute the EndRequest event.
```

The IIS server is set up to use the Integrated Pipeline Mode in the IIS Appication Pool, and when chaning it to Classic, the download works again.

However, I would really like to get it to work with the Integrated setting, so I change my Project in Visual Studio to use Integrated Managed Pipleline Mode and change the code to add headers in the new way.

**Classic Pipeline Mode**

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
```

**Integrated Pipeline Mode**

```
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
```

But, the problem reimains

I discover that the HTTP response headers are never set in the published application, but with the local it is.

**When running the application locally via Visual Studio I get the following HTTP response:**

- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
- Cache-Control: private
- Content-Length: 5885
- Content-Type: image/jpeg; charset=utf-8
- Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
- X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
- Content-disposition: attachment;filename=picture.jpg
- X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVEZTXF...
- X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
- Date: Wed, 23 Sep 2015 15:38:31 GMT

**Running the published IIS application I get:**

- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
- Cache-Control: private
- Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
- Vary: Accept-Encoding
- Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
- X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
- X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
- Date: Wed, 23 Sep 2015 15:37:05 GMT
- Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: How is the initial call to the server made? through a DirectEvent or DirectMethod? If either of those were used to initiate the request, then the client is expect a certain type of response back from the server. Clearing the Response and rebuilding with another format will cause the BADRESPONSE error you noted.